# Image Caching not working?

Tags: ios, iphone

Hello everyone i’m new to ios development , i’m doing JSON parsing and fetch the data and showing on the UITableView with ImageView and Title, Everything works great but image Cacheing is a problem in my code my images are loading but it takes so much time and when i scroll my tableview it again fetch the required image for the cell. Can anybody please come up with caching solution in my present code i already googled many times but unable to figure out this. It really helpful if anyone please suggest me the similar example or assist me on this. Thanks In Advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/consumer_id=1”];    
    NSData *postData = [ post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
    {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);

        NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"%d",success);
        data = [jsonData objectForKey:@"data"];


    }
}
```

#pragma mark - Table view data source

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [data count];
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *myNames = [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNames);

    [cell.nameLabel setText:[myNames objectForKey:@"name"]];

    NSString *imageURL = [myNames objectForKey:@"image"];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];

    UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"license.png"];

    NSLog(@"ImageIcon %@",imageIcon);

    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImage:imageIcon];

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: Instead of loading imageData in main thread in cellForRowAtIndexPath use GCD(Grand Central Dispatch). Search "GCD for loading images in tableview" in google and you will get various sample code related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Show the image asynchronously in with setting placeholder image as your images are coming from web service.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

[image setImageWithURL:your url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

});
```

Try this SDWebImage from [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {


NSMutableArray *arrtInvitationList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *  urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Url"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSError *error1;
     NSDictionary *res=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error1];

 // you are getting dictinary here according ur dictinary parse the data .......

     if ([[res valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
         NSLog(@"%d",[[res valueForKey:@"result"] count]);

         for (int i=0; i<[[res valueForKey:@"result"] count]; i++)
         {
             NSMutableDictionary *dict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             //[dict setObject:[[[[res valueForKey:@"player1"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:i] ];

             [arrtInvitationList addObject:dict];
             [tblInvite reloadData];
         }
         [HUD hide:YES];

     }else
     {
         [HUD hide:YES];

     }

 }];



}


  //After that add this array your table view there also when u adding image add asynchronous method

      NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         UIImage *imagemain=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
                  CGSize size=imagemain.size;
         UIImage *compimage=[self resizeImage:imagemain resizeSize:CGSizeMake(45,45)];
//
         Cell.imgProfile.image=compimage;
//         //         CGSize size1=compimage.size;
//     }];


  this adding image to cell and resize the image also........

  -(UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)orginalImage resizeSize:(CGSize)size
  {
CGFloat actualHeight = orginalImage.size.height;
CGFloat actualWidth = orginalImage.size.width;
//  if(actualWidth <= size.width && actualHeight<=size.height)
//  {
//      return orginalImage;
//  }
float oldRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
float newRatio = size.width/size.height;
if(oldRatio < newRatio)
{
    oldRatio = size.height/actualHeight;
    actualWidth = oldRatio * actualWidth;
    actualHeight = size.height;
}
else
{
    oldRatio = size.width/actualWidth;
    actualHeight = oldRatio * actualHeight;
    actualWidth = size.width;
}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,actualWidth,actualHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[orginalImage drawInRect:rect];
orginalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return orginalImage;
    }
```